# Detect template presence at compilation time

Tags: c++, configuration, templates, c++11

GCC up to 4.5 doesn't have standard C++0x type trait template `has_nothrow_move_constructor`.  I could use it in my package for optimization, but I don't want to rule out one of the common compilers and don't want to overload configuration with symbols like `HAVE_STD_HAS_NOTHROW_MOVE_CONSTRUCTOR`.  Is it somehow possible to use that template if present and just fall back to copying if not present *without* using any predefined configuration symbols?  I also don't want to depend on Boost, since my library is small and doesn't need Boost for any other reasons.

In pseudocode, I need something like:

```
template <typename type>
struct has_nothrow_move_constructor_robust
  : public integral_constant <bool,
           /* if possible */  has_nothrow_move_constructor <type>::value
           /* otherwise   */  false>
{ };
```

Since move constructors are only for C++0x anyway, I don't mind using other C++0x features for the above definition, if at all possible.

Comment: Most of Boost is implemented in header files, not object files. So if you stick to those, you pay no size penalty for things that you do not use - nor for most things that you do use, for that matter.

Comment: It's more of having a dependency (even if almost everyone uses Boost anyway).  Maybe I could tear out the relevant part of Boost, but since my library is like 3 headers anyway...

Comment: It seems kind of hard to check if a type exists. But then, if there is no move constructor, wouldn't C++0x generally automatically fall back to copying? Or if the nothrow part matters, isn't it a bit hard to imagine a class where copying is any safer than moving (if the latter is not marked nothrow)?

Comment: @UncleBens: Yes, C++0x fallbacks on copying (using lvalue-ref) if there is no matching function (in this case, constructor) accepting rvalue-ref.  I also cannot come up with a logical usecase where copying constructor doesn't throw, yet move constructor does.  However, I wouldn't base a library on such assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

`boost::variant` has an implementation of `has_nothrow_move` for its own internal use - you could use that, although it's not as reliable as a proper compiler implementation would be. The source for it is [here](http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#Ky9Sj9jMtgo/trunk/source/fbxcmd/Libraries/boost_1_39_0/boost/variant/detail/has_nothrow_move.hpp&q=variant%20detail%20boost%201_39&d=8) - I don't know how reliable it is, so YMMV.

Apart from that, you could test compiler version macros ([`__GNUC__` and `__GNUC_MINOR__`](http://www.nscee.edu/Cluster/C-intel/doc/c_ug/lin1077.htm)) to determine presence, and stub it out if not present. Unfortunately it seems `has_nothrow_move_constructor` isn't supported in any released version of G++ yet, so you'll have to wait a bit before you'll know the right version to use.